# In Excel how to count between date1 and date2 that have cells in row that contain text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to choose cells in one column that are between two dates, and then based on the rows that contain those dates, choose cells in another row that also contains content.

I didn't use `ISBLANK` because it counts a formula yet an empty cell as a not-blank. Instead check if there is content by `"*"`.

Here is what I came up with, but instead of returning the number of cells, instead this returns `TRUE` (which obviously isn't what I want).

In the formula below I am assuming:

- `C:C` is the whole column containing **DATES**.
- `E:E` is the whole column containing **CONTENT**.
- The date range in this case is **January 1, 2018** to **January 31, 2018**.
- `"*"` means is there is content in the cell

  `=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(C:C,">="&"2018-1-1",C:C,"<="&"2018-1-31"),COUNTIF(E:E,"*"))=0,"",AND(COUNTIFS(C:C,">="&"2018-1-1",C:C,"<="&"2018-1-31"),COUNTIF(E:E,"*")))`

**My goal is to**:

- count the numbers of the cells in column `E` that are between the dates in column `C`
- if the whole formula is `0`, then return a blank.

See this picture of a sample excel sheet to make my intent clear:

[image: excel sheet]

How can I get my formula working so it does as needed?

---

**SOLUTION**

---

Hi all, so thanks to @girlvsdata, we have a working solution. I had to do a couple edits to her code to work for my uses, but her formula overall works perfect. Here is the solution:

To choose all cells in column E that are not blank, in between the date range of all of January (unknown end date) based on the adjacent C column if that is your date column, then the solution is:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(C:C,">="&"2018-1-1",C:C,"<="&EOMONTH("2018-1-1",0),E:E,"*")=0,"",COUNTIFS(C:C,">="&"2018-1-1",C:C,"<="&EOMONTH("2018-1-1",0),E:E,"*"))
```

Note that `"2018-1-1"` is January 1 2018, and `EOMONTH("2018-1-1",0)` is the last valid day of January in the year 2018 (in this case, 31, but if it is different another year *(e.g. for February this works for leap years too)* then it will be that last day). Also it eliminates the need to calculate which is the last day or every month, as well as months that have changing end dates dependent on the year (e.g. Feb). **This is important to eliminate a margin of error**.

The only thing you have to do to change the month is only change e.g. `-1-` (Jan) to `-2-` for Feb, or change the year for other years. With this formula you can ignore the day part.

If the answer is 0 (no cells have any content in between the range), then the cell is blank instead of 0. (GOod for when you want to create a sheet checking future dates for future reference when more rows are added to the sheet.

It also works across different sheets, just use, say your other sheet is called "Tracker" then use `Tracker!C:C` and `Tracker!E:E`. Hope it helps!

Thank you all! :D

Comment: Are those 'dates' really text that looks like dates or did you force left alignment?

Comment: ✱ isn't an asterisk; it is unicode character 10033.

Comment: @Jeeped it is actually dates, and I forced left alignment in that particular sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Please note: My local date format is day, then month)*

**With the data laid out as in your example above:**

```
       A          B
1     Dates     |Content
    ------------+-------
2   1/01/2018   |
3   2/01/2018   |123456
4   3/01/2018   |
5   4/01/2018   |12398
6   5/01/2018   |484
7   6/01/2018   |1538
8   7/01/2018   |
9   8/01/2018   |   
10  9/01/2018   |
11  10/01/2018  |14648
12  11/01/2018  |
13  12/01/2018  |145615
14  13/01/2018  |
```

**And with the date range in cells `D2` and `E2`:**

```
Date Start  Date End
2/01/2018   7/01/2018
```

**This formula returns the count:**

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&D2,A:A,"<="&E2,B:B,">0")
```

This will depend on whether your numbers in `Column B` are formatted as text or number. If they are formatted as numbers, the above formula will work. If they are formatted as text, replace the last section `">0"` with `"*"`.

**This formula adds the conditional part of your question:**

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&D2,A:A,"<="&E2,B:B,">0")=0,"",COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&D2,A:A,"<="&E2,B:B,">0"))
```

(If the formula returns 0, show blank)

Comment: How do I define a date? I need to begin at start of month (even if it does not exist in the date column) and end at the end of the month (even if it does not exist in the date column). Often, the first or last day will not exist in the date column, but I need to include all days in a specified month even if that first or last date doesn't actually exist in the date column.

Comment: You can either have the date range in some cells in the workbook (I used `D2` and `E2`) or you can replace those cell references with your dates.

Comment: Ok, and will this work when I do not know whether or not the start or end date actually exists (but I want all cells in between those two specified dates counted)? **e.g. start jan 1, end jan 31 (if that is the last day of that month): it counts all cells, even if the first to exist in date column is, say, jan 3.**

Comment: Yep, it's a range that will catch any values that fall between those two dates, including the start date and end date.

Comment: How do I formulate the date? e.g. `2018-1-31`?

Comment: Try formatting the same way as your dates are formatted on the spreadsheet. From your screenshot I believe they were `/`s not `-`s. My date formatting will be very different to yours, as date formatting in Excel is regional.

Comment: Yes I also tried `1/1/2018` and `1/31/2018`, but that also returned blank (I see it returns 0 which it makes blank). Take a look at some dates on my sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS7UE.jpg

Comment: Try testing with something smaller. Point a simple formula towards a cell, eg if `A1` contains the date `1/3/2018`, then see if a formula like this will work: `=A1="1/3/2018"` and test until it works. I've just tried it, it looks like you are having an issue because you are trying to compare a string with a date, where my answer is pointing to a cell with date formatting (comparing like with like). So you could do something like DATE(2018,1,31) to use date formatting.

Comment: Oh I think I know the problem. You used method whether the content column is greater than 0. However, the "content" column does not only contain numbers. Also dashes or letters. That's why my original was to check if `*` to see if the cell was empty or not.

Comment: Let me try to simply replace `">0"` with `"*"` and see if that works... **Update** YEP! `"*"` is the correct solution. Please note it even worked even though I still used format `1-31-2018` for the dates.

Comment: Update: I tried February now but it returns blank. I need it to work even if the end date or beginning does doesn't exist in the column. I put `2018-2-29` to include leap years even though 29 does not exist in the column, but it only works if I put `2018-2-28` as the end date and 2-28 does exist. This is problematic because then it won't show on dates where the date didn't exist in the column.

Comment: I did this instead to fix that problem! `EOMONTH("2018-2-1",0)`. I think that worked. Meaning now I only need to put that for the end dates, e.g. for March 2018 I put `EOMONTH("2018-3-1",0)`.

Comment: I tested extensively and the `EOMONTH` solution I suggested in the comment above seems to work every time! Thanks so much for your answer, now I have it working! p.s. to future readers: `EOMONTH("2018-3-1",0)` means end of March 2018. The `0` at the end indicated the end of the current month in the date specified *(it ignores the day of `1`, the final result, for example, if March has 30 days, then the end result of `EOMONTH("2018-3-1",0)` is actually `2018-03-30` - you can do this without knowing the actual end of the month (Excel knows)).*